# Ubuntu is 12 (20/10/16)

Tags: discussion

Just thought I would post this I found on [OMG Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/10/ubuntu-12th-birthday), seems very appropriate here :)

Today is Ubuntu's 12th birthday, Happy Birthday Ubuntu!!!

[image]

The OMG Ubuntu link contains an Ubuntu quiz you can take to test your Ubuntu knowledge.

Comment: Yay! We've survived 12 years of haters!

Comment: And mannny mooooorrrrre @Zacharee1

Comment: I want that cake!!! :D

Comment: what a cool idea to celebrate the birthday of an OS. who knows? maybe robots will celebrate their birthdays on their own one day!

Comment: Cake is as attractive as the OS itself!